# Taxonomy is not selected after imported csv data from phpMyadmin

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I created Taxonomies and assign them on Page field with radio buttons and "unlimited" number of values. Meaning each node can have more than 1 taxonomy. And these taxonomy fields did show on "add content" or "edit" content, which is right. So, I was trying to mapping these taxonomy with pages by phpMyadmin. Imported CSV data into "taxonomy_index" table(just like the way they listed), and these pages did show under each taxonomy term. However, when I try to edit these nodes, these taxonomies are NOT selected. Am I missing something?

*here is my csv file should look* -

"166","61","0","1276016485"
"166","53","0","1276016485"
"170","53","0","1276016485"
"170","51","0","1276016485"

Comment: The difference between Drupal 6 and 7 is important in this case. Which are you using?

Comment: It's on my Drupal 7.